# css selecting lists and list items

Tags: css, list

I have a css file that has a section that looks like

```
.mylist ul { ..configuration .. }
.mylist li { ..configuration .. }
```

If the html looks like

```
<div class="mylist">
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The styling is applied properly.

If I do

```
  <ul class="mylist">
    <li>item1</li>
  </ul>
```

It does not seem to be.

Why do I need that extra div tag? Shouldn't the styling apply the same way in either case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.mylist ul` means an `ul` as subitem of `.mylist`.

Try this:

```
ul.mylist { ..configuration .. }
ul.mylist li { ..configuration .. }
```

With:

```
<ul class="mylist">
  <li>item1</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ding ding ding!  You got it.  You can also just remove the `ul.mylist` and go for the unadulterated `.mylist, .mylist li`

Comment: @TimBolton - Your absolutly correct. Both ways works fine in this case.